# VB6 CALC Aggregation on ADO Shape when returns Null getting General Error in Data Report

Tags: sql-server, vb6, ado

I am using ado shape command on my data report, it works fine but when my aggregate function CALC(agrProfit/agrExtended*100) is null or 0/0*100 it shows general error and data report not showing up. Please Help.

```
mRS.Open "SHAPE {select products.productid,products.productcode,isnull(products.description,descr) as description,isnull(vendor.description,'*** NOT FOUND ***') as groupdescription, " & _
    "isnull(sum(totalcost),0) as mTotalCost,isnull(sum(extended) - (sum(totalcost)),0) as mProfit,  " & _
    "sum(charges) as mCharges,sum(discount) as mDiscounts, sum(retextended) as mReturns, " & _
    "reportuom, sum(totalcost) as mTotalCost, isnull(case when sum(extended) = 0 then 0 else (sum(extended) - (sum(totalcost)))/sum(extended)*100 end,0)  as mgpm, sum(totalcost) as mTotalCost, case when sum(extended) = 0 then 0 else (sum(extended) - (sum(totalcost)))/sum(extended)*100 end  as mgpm, sum(case when extended < 0 then  (0 - (totalqty/products.reportqty))  else (totalqty/products.reportqty) end) as mTotalQty, isnull(sum(extended),0) as mExtended,  sum(case when extended < 0 then  (0 - (totalqty/products.reportqty)) else (totalqty/products.reportqty) end) / " & mTotalQty & " * 100 as mPercTotalQty, sum(extended) / " & mTotalExtended & " * 100 as mPercExtended " & _
    "From " & _
        "(select finishedsales.QtyReturned,finishedsales.productid,finishedsales.description as descr, finishedsales.averageunitcost* case when [return]=1 then convert(money,0-totalqty) else totalqty end as TotalCost,(chargeallowance * qty) + (chargeamountdiscounted * qty) as charges,(allowance * qty) + (amountdiscounted * qty)+ (extended-(extended * multiplier)) as discount,0 as rettotalqty, 0 as retextended,totalqty,round(extended * multiplier,4) as extended  From finishedsales " & _
        " left join products on products.productid = finishedsales.productid " & _
        .gReportCriteria & _
        "Union All " & _
        "select finishedsales.QtyReturned, finishedsales.productid,finishedsales.description as descr,0 as totalcost,0 as charges,0 as discount,totalqty as rettotalqty ,abs(round(extended,4)) as retextended,0 as totalqty, 0 as extended From finishedsales " & _
            "left join products on products.productid = finishedsales.productid " & _
        Replace(UCase(.gReportCriteria & " and [RETURN] = 1"), "[RETURN] = 0", "[return] = 1") & _
    ") as finishedsales " & _
    "left join products on products.productid=finishedsales.productid  " & _
    "left join vendor on products.vendorcode=vendor.vendorcode " & _
    "group by descr,products.productid,products.productcode,products.description,vendor.description,reportuom " & _
    "order by groupdescription, " & IIf(frmReportProducts.chkTop And fVal(frmReportProducts.txtTop) > 0, "finishedsales.mtotalqty desc,", "") & " products.description}  AS Command1 COMPUTE Command1, SUM(Command1.mTotalQty) AS agrTotalQty,  SUM(Command1.mExtended) AS agrExtended, SUM(Command1.mProfit) AS agrProfit, CALC(agrProfit/agrExtended*100) As agrGPM BY groupdescription", mcn
```

Comment: Is this in MS Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you're using the [ADO Data Shaping functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676186(v=vs.85).aspx) here, and the `CALC(expression)` allows you to use VBA functions listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675033(v=vs.85).aspx) within the expression. @C-Pound Guru's suggestion causes an error since NULLIF() is not a VBA function, but the whole expression can be rewritten like this:

```
CALC(IIF(IsNull(agrProfit), 0, IIF(agrProfit=0, 0, agrProfit/agrExtended) *100))
```

Let me know if this takes care of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL Server is 2005 or newer you can use [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562(v=sql.90).aspx) in conjunction with [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325(v=sql.90).aspx):

Replace `agrProfit/agrExtended` with

```
ISNULL(agrProfit / NULLIF(agrExtended,0),0)
```

This will return zero when agrExtended=0 rather than causing a divide by zero error.

Comment: CALC(ISNULL(agrProfit/NULLIF(agrExtended*100,0),0))

it says Column NULLIF was used in a CALC expression but is not defined in the rowset

Comment: Calc isn't a built in SQL function (as far as I know). Perhaps you can show that function and we can see if the divide by zero can be handled there...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using MS Access or something that interfaces with MS Access. If that is the case, maybe you can use `Switch`:

Replace:

`CALC(agrProfit / agrExtended * 100)`

With:

```
Switch(
  ISNULL(SUM(Command1.mExtended)), 0,
  ISNULL(SUM(Command1.mProfit)), 0,
  IIF(SUM(Command1.mExtended) = 0, 0, SUM(Command1.mProfit) / SUM(Command1.mExtended) * 100)
      )
```

The idea is to replace `NULL` with 0, replace Divide by 0 with 0, or else return the actual ratio.